# get variable from Jframe class in abstract class

Tags: java

My problem that I want to get variable from jframe class to abstract class in java

exemple:

```
public class MainWindow extends Frame {
    String Variable 1;
    ..... 
}

public abstract class AbstractController { 

    // I need to use variable 1 in this class...

}
```

thank for all...

Comment: in AbstractController `MainWindow test=new MainWindow(); test.getVariable1();`. think about naming conventions. variable names should always start with a lower case and cant be a number

Comment: Likely you would pass the view into the controller, perhaps in a constructor parameter, and then the controller would call public methods on the view if it needed to extract its state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My problem that I want get variable from jframe class to abstract class in java

I'm going to suggest that no, you really don't want to do that, you don't want to directly access and modify variables from one class in another. You appear to be creating something akin to a model-view-controller or view-controller, and so you will likely want to pass references as needed, encapsulate all variables, and access variables or "states" through controlled public methods. So something like so:

```
public class View {
    private String someStateField;
    //..... 

    public String getSomeStateField() {
        return someStateField;
    }

    public void setSomeStateField(String someStateField) {
        this.someStateField = someStateField;
    }
}
```

and the controller

```
public abstract class AbstractController { 
    private View view;

    public AbstractController(View view) {
        this.view = view;
    }

    public view getView() {
        return view;
    }

    public void someMethod() {
        // can now call view methods here
    }

}
```

Of course the concrete version of your controller will need to have a similarly structured constructor and call the super's constructor:

```
public class ConcreteController { 

    public ConcreteController(View view) {
        super(view);
    }

    // ....

}
```

and the main method would need to hook it all together:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
        View view = new View();
        AbstractController controller = new ConcreteController(view);
        // .....
    });
}
```

The specifics of your solution will of course depend on the rest of your program's structure and set up, and if you need a more detailed answer, then please update your question with greater detail and code, and comment back to me.